# Stop gif image from repeating in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, gif

I searched for other similar questions but that didn't solve my problem. Below is a simple code that generates an animation in the form of a gif image in matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anm

fig = plt.figure()
def draw(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 5, num = 1000)    
    y = np.sin(x-i*0.1)
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r-') 

anim = anm.FuncAnimation(fig, draw, frames = 10, interval = 500, repeat = False)
anim.save('test.gif', fps = 1, writer = 'imagemagick')
```

This generates the animation I want but once I open the final image (with eog), it keeps repeating. Since I would be presenting animation in the presentation, I would like it to stop after it is shown once. As you can notice, I have added `repeat = False` in the FuncAnimation but that doesn't stop repeating the image. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not well documented - but try adding `extra_args=['-loop','1']` to the call to `save` e.g. `anim.save('test.gif', fps = 1, writer = 'imagemagick',extra_args=['-loop','1'])`.  If this works I'll add it as a full answer, but I'm not sure at the moment and don't have `imagemagick` to check.  The `extra_args` are passed straight through to the image encoder.

Comment: No. It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you make it produce some debug output to find what ImageMagick command it is running? It will probably contain the word `convert`. Or, can you run it and at the same time try `while :; do ps -aef | grep "convert" | grep "test.gif"; done`

Comment: I am not very good at bash. So tried running this command while the image was running and that didn't produce any output.

Comment: Maybe you can write the files out to disk as PNG files, and then use ImageMagick yourself with `convert frame*png -loop 1 animation.gif`

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Arggh - found the requisite line in the source and it looks like they hard code `-loop 0`: see [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a4aebe3a9a5f86278db847c9ef11cf1ab11f4ca1/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L629)  I think that's arguably a bug, as the tool defaults it to zero anyway.  I think because of this, any user-specified `-loop` will be ignored.  I think you'll have to output the frames as per @marksetchell and convert manually if you want it not to loop :(

Comment: Nice piece of sleuthing!

Comment: @JRichardSnape,@MarkSetchell : Thanks for the help. I would certainly try this. In the meantime I found a working solution for presentation: while including gif in latex, one can specify whether to loop over or not. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was to change from imagemagick to pillow as a writer.

Try the following:

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(1, 51), interval=.001, repeat=False)
anim.save('test.gif', dpi=80, writer=PillowWriter(fps=5))
```

The quality of the image is a bit worse than with imagemagick from my opinion, but it's a much easier and faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using PillowWriter didn't solve the problem for me, so I came up with a workaround: just remove the loop as a post-processing step with PIL. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

def convert(old_filename, new_filename, duration):
    images = []
    with Image.open(old_filename) as im:
        for i in range(im.n_frames):
            im.seek(i)
            buf = io.BytesIO()
            im.save(buf, format='png')
            buf.seek(0)
            images.append(Image.open(buf))
    images[0].save(new_filename, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], optimize=False, duration=duration)

convert("myAnimation.gif", "myAnimationNoLoop.gif", 100)
```