# The saved animated plot keeps looping although Matplotlib FuncAnimation(...,repeat=False)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'd like to make an animation using `matplotlib` for a powerpoint presentation. The animation should only play once.

In my code, the argument `repeat` of `FuncAnimation()` was set to false.
Because I need to import the figure into powerpoint, I saved it using `ani.save('test.gif')`.
The problem is when I open the saved figure which is test.gif, the lineplot keeps looping.

All the searches on Stackoverflow suggest `repeat=False`, or using [PillowWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111351/stop-gif-image-from-repeating-in-matplotlib). Both solutions are not working for me, so I have two questions:

1. why does the saved figure ignores `repeat=False`?
2. how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for helping me out.
Please, find my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": {
            0: 0,
            1: 1,
            2: 2,
            3: 3,
            4: 4,
            5: 5,
            6: 6,
            7: 7,
            8: 8,
            9: 9,
            10: 10,
            11: 11,
            12: 12,
            13: 13,
            14: 14,
            15: 15,
            16: 16,
            17: 17,
            18: 18,
            19: 19,
            20: 20,
            21: 21,
            22: 22,
            23: 23,
            24: 24,
            25: 25,
            26: 26,
            27: 27,
            28: 28,
            29: 29,
            30: 30,
            31: 31,
            32: 32,
            33: 33,
            34: 34,
            35: 35,
            36: 36,
            37: 37,
            38: 38,
            39: 39,
            40: 40,
            41: 41,
            42: 42,
            43: 43,
            44: 44,
            45: 45,
            46: 46,
            47: 47,
            48: 48,
            49: 49,
            50: 50,
        },
        "y": {
            0: 0.7695,
            1: 0.7983,
            2: 0.7958,
            3: 0.7975,
            4: 0.7983,
            5: 0.7966,
            6: 0.7971,
            7: 0.7962,
            8: 0.7962,
            9: 0.7975,
            10: 0.7983,
            11: 0.7987,
            12: 0.7996,
            13: 0.7992,
            14: 0.7967,
            15: 0.7983,
            16: 0.7971,
            17: 0.7987,
            18: 0.7979,
            19: 0.7983,
            20: 0.7983,
            21: 0.7921,
            22: 0.7975,
            23: 0.7962,
            24: 0.7975,
            25: 0.7979,
            26: 0.7983,
            27: 0.7992,
            28: 0.7983,
            29: 0.7983,
            30: 0.7987,
            31: 0.7983,
            32: 0.7983,
            33: 0.7983,
            34: 0.7992,
            35: 0.7975,
            36: 0.7996,
            37: 0.7992,
            38: 0.7979,
            39: 0.7987,
            40: 0.7983,
            41: 0.7983,
            42: 0.7987,
            43: 0.7987,
            44: 0.7992,
            45: 0.7992,
            46: 0.7979,
            47: 0.7996,
            48: 0.7992,
            49: 0.7987,
            50: 0.7992,
        },
    }
)


x = df["x"]
y = df["y"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color="b")

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    return (line,)

ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line], interval=15, blit=True, repeat=False
)

# ani.save('test.gif')
ani.save("test2.gif", dpi=80, writer=PillowWriter(fps=5))

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this is an issue with powerpoint. I believe it will continue to loop any gifs you put into it?

Comment: The thing is I didn't even imported the test.gif file into powerpoint yet. By just double-clic, the plot animates endlessly.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that GIFs don't encode whether or not they should loop so this isn't something that matplotlib will be able to fix. Like your photo viewer is chosing whether to loop or not. Try saving the plot as a `.mp4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ImageMagickWriter:

```
ani.save("test2.gif", dpi=80, writer=ImageMagickWriter(fps=5, extra_args=['-loop', '1']))
```

I spent a lot of time looking into this. Its a little bit of a hack as '-loop 0' is passed to the movie writer (convert) and the extra_args are appended but override. Here is a GIF I created using extra_args=['-loop', '1']:

[image: Loop once GIF]
NB: Open image in a new tab to see it play.

I never got PillowWriter to work even when overriding the hard coded loop=0 in the [finish() method](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9765379ce6e7343070e815afc0988874041b98e2/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L513):

```
class PillowWriterNG(PillowWriter):
    def finish(self):
            self._frames[0].save(
                self.outfile, save_all=True, append_images=self._frames[1:],
                duration=int(1000 / self.fps), loop=1)
```

Changing the loop parameter from 0 to 1 stops the infinite looping but it still runs twice!

Comment: So, it turns out that repeat=False in FuncAnimation doesn't work with ImageMagick either?
I run into the exact same problem and now I start thinking that matplotlib is kind of a garbage.
Sometimes it is so hard to make a pretty much simple things working...