# Remove loop effect from GIF

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

I am trying to remove the infinite loop effect from a gif I am saving from an animated graph, using python, matplotlib and Pillowwriter. The last one should have by default no loop from the gif, but the gif I get is instead looping. Here is the code, based on random data I have in a csv:

```
import random
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'C:\\Users\\Giacomo\\Desktop\\Cartel1.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data_url, sep='\;', header=0)
x,y=[], []
y1=data.x
t=data.y


def animate(i):
    x.append(t[i])
    y.append((y1[i]))
    plt.plot(x,y, scaley=True, scalex=True, color="darkred")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axes.set_ylim(0, 2)
axes.set_xlim(0, 55)
plt.style.use("seaborn-pastel")

anim = FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, interval=100)

f = r"Desktop/animation5.gif" 
writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=10) 
anim.save(f, writer=writergif, duration=100, loop=0)
```

If I pass the loopor duration arguments in the save(9 I got the error for unexpected arguments, but I saw someone used it in other examples...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The saved animated plot keeps looping although Matplotlib FuncAnimation(...,repeat=False)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529921/the-saved-animated-plot-keeps-looping-although-matplotlib-funcanimation-repe)

Comment: I tried, and it shows me a not loop graph but does not save the gif anymore....